Do I really need a fuse to bypass a tube light ballast?
The electrical diagram for a GE type b LED T8 says that after removing the ballast they recommend I should add an inline 1A fuse. Is this just them covering themselves or is it really important that I add one?
If so, where should I get one? I couldn’t find one on Lowe’s’ website but I don’t want to trust random components I find on Amazon.

The reason they recommend adding a fuse is in case someone tries to put a fluorescent tube in a fixture that has had the ballast removed.
There is a GE kit with the fuse holder and fuse, part number BT8-1AFUSEKIT, a search should find a number of sources for them.
It's not required in order to meet code as far as I know, but it is recommended.
